# I'm trying to install Google Assistant but encounter an error that I can't find a solution anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-assistant

I'm trying to install Google Assistant but I encountered an error like this:
Someone please help me fix this
I followed the instruction in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfVMXq6mEXk&t=623s

````
Press Enter to send a new request...
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hello".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "help".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hello".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hello".
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hello".
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 469, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 458, in main
    continue_conversation = assistant.assist()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 241, in wrapped_f
    return self.call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 329, in call
    do = self.iter(result=result, exc_info=exc_info,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 279, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 433, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 333, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 154, in assist
    self.conversation_stream.write(resp.audio_out.audio_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\audio_helpers.py", line 326, in write
    buf = normalize_audio_buffer(buf, self.volume_percentage)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\audio_helpers.py", line 57, in normalize_audio_buffer
    buf = arr.tostring()
AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'tostring'```
````

Comment: Could you share the code as well ?

Comment: To make an array in python to a string. You must use str(Array)